# React: sync with the localstorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, webapi

Have a React app. Some specific component would be setting different data values with same key to localstorage over a time. I need to have few components subscribed to that item in the localstorage. Whenever the value with the specific key is updated in the localstorage, the subscribed components should be notified or provided with the updated value in the localstorage.

I tried creating a custom hook for this and using with by adding a event listener to the `storage` event as follow.

```
const useSyncLocalStorage = (key: string) => {
  const [storageVal, setStorageVal] = useState<string | null>(() => localStorage.getItem(key));

  const handleStorageChange = () => {
    const value = localStorage.getItem(key);
    setStorageVal(value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('storage', handleStorageChange);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('storage', handleStorageChange);
    };
  }, []);

  return storageVal;
};
```

And using it in the component as follow:

```
const locationStored = useSyncLocalStorage('location');
```

I tried updating the locastorage value on a click event, but the hook does not return the updated value in the localstorage. I verified the localstorage value is updated in the dev tools. The issue seems that the `storage` event is not triggered in the same window/tab that caused the storage change.

Is there any way to subscribe to the localstorage value?

Answer (score 0):

The approach you've taken is correct, but you're right that the storage event won't be triggered in the same window/tab that caused the storage change. The storage event is designed to notify other windows or tabs that the storage has been modified by a different window or tab.

In your case, since you're updating the localStorage value within the same window, the storage event won't be fired, and thus your subscribed components won't receive the update.

To overcome this limitation, you can modify your custom hook to use a different mechanism for notifying subscribed components about changes in the localStorage value. One approach is to use a separate event system, such as the React Context API or a state management library like Redux, to handle communication between components.

Comment: Yes, Redux or Context API can be ways of sharing the data here, but the case here is the data to be shared isn't going to be produce by a React component directly, it is going to be via view model by the backend.

Comment: If the data is being updated by the backend and you need to notify your React components about those changes, you can consider using a real-time communication mechanism like WebSocket to establish a connection between the frontend and the backend.

WebSocket to notify React components about changes in the backend data:
1. Set up a WebSocket connection on the frontend
2. On the backend, whenever the data changes, send the updated value through the WebSocket connection
3. The frontend listens for WebSocket messages and updates the React component accordingly.
@AbhinandanKhilari

Answer (score 0):

I found myself what is the wrong part, you can combine [useLocalStorage](https://usehooks-ts.com/react-hook/use-local-storage)
and local-storage event, you need to call below line everytime you update localStorage, all components will know by using useLocalStorage hook

> window.dispatchEvent(new Event('local-storage'));